# How to make reverse object?

Tags: php, laravel

in Laravel controller

```
$groups = ProductGroup::all();
  return view('seller.index',['groups'=>array_reverse($groups)];
```

how to make it correctly?

Comment: Please outline exactly what you want to achieve, including the data from `ProductGroup::all()`, and what you want `$groups` to end up like.

Comment: ProductGroup::all()->toArray(); or even better array_flatten(ProductGroup::all()->toArray())

Comment: $groups - is the array of objects, I want to reverse it.

Comment: ProductGroup::all()->toArray(); or even better array_flatten(ProductGroup::all()->toArray()) we must return object also, not array

Comment: Then maybe, as suggested in the answer, you need to change the query and get the collection in descending order

Answer (score 3):

Use [reverse()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-reverse):

```
return view( 'seller.index', [ 'groups' => $groups->reverse() ];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get new records then you should try:

```
$groups = ProductGroup::orderBy("created_at,"DESC")->get();
return view('seller.index',['groups'=>$groups];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups_reversed = clone (object)array_reverse((array)$groups);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!